# How do I SCP repo files using GitHub Actions?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, scp, github-actions

I'm trying to implement a GitHub action that will SCP my repo files to a server on a push to the master branch. I have a similar setup working on Bitbucket Pipelines, but now that I'm learning to do this with GitHub actions, I'm not having any luck.

My project is a simple [Node.js app](https://github.com/SamSverko/flatbread), where I would like to simply scp all the files to the server, then I will run a post-scp script to `npm i` once the new files are copied to the server. Just want to keep things simple while I'm learning.

I'm using the [scp-files GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scp-files). Here is my file:

```
name: Deploy to production

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: SCP files to server
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: SCP files via ssh key
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        env:
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY }}
        with:
          source: './*'
          target: '/home/ubuntu/flatbread/'
```

This action is able to complete the `Set up job` and `Build appleboy/scp-action@master`. But it errors out when it runs `appleboy/scp-action@master`. This is the error I receive:

```
tar: empty archive
exit status 1
tar all files into /tmp/320558105/i2yG360Zje.tar
##[error]Docker run failed with exit code 1
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Even if I change the `source: './*'` to a sample folder (i.e. `source: app`), it still gives me the same error.

---

**Update**

If I change the `source: './*'` to `source: '.'`, that seems to do the trick in terms of no more GitHub action errors:

```
tar all files into /tmp/719605837/1uYygkf4Vn.tar
scp file to server.
create folder /home/***/flatbread/
untar file 1uYygkf4Vn.tar
remove file 1uYygkf4Vn.tar
================================================
Successfully executed transfer data to all host.
================================================
```

Unfortunately, upon verifying the files on the server, no changes have been made to it. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Based on your update, it looks like more of an issue with the `appleboy/scp-action@master` action.  You may get more traction by filing an issue in that repository.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. Although I have tried a bunch of similar scp-actions from different providers, and they all have the same effect. I'll try reaching out.

Comment: any way to scp only the pushed files. Something like a git pull?

Answer (score 24):

Hope this helps!

- First you create a folder *outside* your repo
- Then you copy all of your repo content into it
- Then you tar it
- Upload to the server

```
name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        mkdir ../build
        cp -TR . ../build
        tar -cvf deploy.tar ../build/

    - name: copy file via ssh password
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        source: "deploy.tar"
        target: "destination/folder"
```

Comment: Great! Thats exactly what I was looking for Thank You!

Comment: Please mention how you got the post deploy script running.

Comment: @ManiKumarReddyKancharla you just add additional steps, but I always put a little delay step about 15 seconds before I run next step.

Comment: how do I SCP via proxy host from GitHub actions?